# Liftweb submenus with Loc definition

Tags: scala, lift

There are [several](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.2.html) explanations for SiteMap definition with submenus. But they all rely on a Menu definition in this form:

```
Menu.i("Info") / "info" submenus(
  Menu.i("About") / "about" >> Hidden >> LocGroup("bottom"),
  Menu.i("Contact") / "contact",
  Menu.i("Feedback") / "feedback" >> LocGroup("bottom"))
```

However, my menu definition looks like this, rather:

```
  val AdminLoginRequired = User.loginFirst
  val sitemap = List(
    Menu(Loc("Home", "index" :: Nil, "Home")),
    Menu(Loc("Admin", "admin" :: Nil, "Admin", AdminLoginRequired, LocGroup("admin")))
  ) ::: Customer.menus ::: User.menus ::: Product.menus
```

I now have `Product.admin_menus`:

```
def viewProductMenuLoc = Full(Menu(Loc("ViewProduct" + menuNameSuffix, viewPath, S.?("view.product"))))

def editProductMenuLoc = Full(Menu(Loc("EditProduct" + menuNameSuffix, editPath, S.?("edit.product"))))

def listProductsMenuLoc = Full(Menu(Loc("ListProducts" + menuNameSuffix, listPath, S.?("list.products"))))

def indexProductsMenuLoc = Full(Menu(Loc("IndexProducts" + menuNameSuffix, indexPath, S.?("index.products"))))

def createProductMenuLoc = Full(Menu(Loc("CreateProduct" + menuNameSuffix, createPath, S.?("create.product"))))

lazy val admin_sitemap: List[Menu] = List(editProductMenuLoc, createProductMenuLoc, indexProductsMenuLoc).flatten(a => a)
```

I would like to make `admin_sitemap` a submenu to the admin menu above. Is that even possible with this definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just pass the submenus as the second parameter to Menu. So:

```
val AdminLoginRequired = User.loginFirst
val sitemap = List(
  Menu(Loc("Home", "index" :: Nil, "Home")),
  Menu(
    Loc("Admin", "admin" :: Nil, "Admin", AdminLoginRequired, LocGroup("admin")),
    admin_sitemap: _*
  )
) ::: Customer.menus ::: User.menus ::: Product.menus
```

However you can convert the old "direct" format to the new dsl format. Assuming you don't need to localize the menu labels, and you don't care about the menus' internal names:

```
val sitemap = List(
  Menu("Home") / "index",
  Menu("Admin" / "admin" >> AdminLoginRequired >> LocGroup("admin") submenus (admin_sitemap: _*)
)) ::: Customer.menus ::: User.menus ::: Product.menus
```

To make the label localizable, use `Menu.i` instead of plain `Menu`, and to specify the internal name pass it first, as in `Menu("MenuHome", "Home")`. Apparently you can't do that with `Menu.i` (I guess no one thought of it).